# Does a positive real function tending towards $0$ have a corresponding "convex line of best fit" with respect to area?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, convex-analysis, problem-solving

> Let $\ f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+\ $ be continuous, such that $\
>  \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0.\ $ Does there exist a
> **convex** function $\ g:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+\ $ such that $\ \displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^{a} g(x) - f(x)\ dx = 0\ ?\ $

So in some sense, $\ g(x)\ $ is the "line of best fit" of $\ f(x).$

[image]

Comment: I believe using the ham sandwich theorem and a piecewise linear function you can find one. I would not expect it to be unique.

Comment: What's the ham sandwich theorem? Not heard of that before

Comment: The Ham sandwich theorem shows that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ any $n$ measurable sets can be split in half with a single $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane. The analogy here is that you can split a ham sandwich so that each slice of bread and the ham are each perfectly halved with a single cut. For plane figures like a graph this means I can take two areas and cut both of them in half with a single line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem

Comment: I see. Do you have a proof then as per your first comment?

Comment: Not a proof just some geometric intuition. Partition the graph like you're setting up a Riemann sum then try to divide each section in half using line segments with increasing slope. However if the graph is unbounded anywhere, like say $\frac1x \sin x$ I'm hesitant to trust my intuition. The two dimensional case of the ham sandwich theorem is essentially the mean value theorem, a somewhat stronger statement. It's what makes me suspect it may be possible in all cases.